# Project source or published DLL's?

Tags: reusability

When reusing code (for example, a Util library you created), do you add its project to your solution or use a compiled/published DLL from the Util library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an assembly is mature, not likely to change or I'm fairly certain I won't need to step into it I would reference the DLL. If it's likely that changes will be made in the assembly's project or it's likely I'll want to step into it, I reference the project.

Comment: you can also step into a .dll if you publish the .pdb file

Answer (score 0):

I add the project if I want to be sure to have all changes and the latest version of the library.  Then I can update the library project when I am updating my whole solution.

If I want to be certain that I am using a specific version of the library, I'll just add the dll.

Edit: Also, what Mitch said.